# Non existence of a retraction (2)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How do you prove that there are no retractions from the torus $T$ to the image of $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is any continuous function from $S^1$ to $T$? In our course we covered the basic aspects of algebraic topology (homotopies, fundamental groups and coverings); the only thing that came up to my mind is that if there is a retraction $r$ from $T$ to $A$ (let's call $A$ the image of $\gamma$), then the two homomorphisms $i_* $ (where $i:A\hookrightarrow T$) and $r_*$ must satisfy $r_* \circ i_* = \operatorname {Id}$. This statement is true because the fundamental group is a functor from topological spaces to groups; however I think it's useful only if we are trying to retract a simply connected space to a non simply conected space. In that case it's clear that $r_* \circ i_*$ cannot be the identity.

However here the case is different, and reasoning in this way doesn't lead to an absurd: in fact there exist for sure two homomorphisms, say $\phi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times\mathbb Z$ and $\varphi : \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, such that $\varphi \circ \phi = \operatorname {Id}$. So this necessary condition is satisfied, and I don't know what else to do. Thanks in advance for every help.

Comment: If you allow an arbitrary $\gamma$, then the image may be $T$ itself (space filling curve). I guess you have to consider embeddings.

Comment: @PaulFrost I think you're right. Also, can we convert this problem to the disk and the circle situation? By considering the torus to be a square with opposite edges identified. I don't know..

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't understand very well your comment, I think that it goes beyond my notions. I just know that by definition every map $S^1 \to T$ represents an element of the fundamental group of $T$.

Comment: The torus is $T\cong S^1\times S^1$. There are loads of different (and obvious) retractions. You implicitly wrote down two of them already!

Comment: @Dorian There are continuous $\gamma : S^1 \to T$ such that $\gamma(S^1) = T$. I think you do not want to consider this case.